# Utilizando useState no react mas não está conforme imagino

Tags: react

Pelo que entendi o **useState**, é utilizando dentro de uma mesma função para atualizar variável ou componente html dentro da mesma função.

O que preciso é:

Tenho um formulário é nele eu preciso chamar métodos em outro arquivo. Até aqui tudo bem, funciona. Isto é, vai lá no banco de dados, busca e traz os resultados e preenche a variável.

O problema é que não está atualizando o componente.

```
const FormularioPrincipalView = () => {

    const pivotPrincipal = useRef<Pivot | null>(null);
    const [listaPrincpal, setListaPrincpal] = useState([]);     

    const reportPrincipal = {
        dataSource: {
            data: listaPrincpal,
        },
        slice: {
            rows: [
            {uniqueName: "nome" },
            {uniqueName: "aniversario" }
            ]
        }
    };
    <Pivot
    ref={pivotPrincipal}
    toolbar
    report={reportPrincipal}
    height="450"
    />
}
```

A chamada agora está assim:

```
export const pesquisaPrincipal = (item: PesquisaGusa) => {
    Promise.all([
    pesquisa(item).then(resp => {
        if (resp && resp.principal.length > 0) {
        pivotPrincipal.current.flexmonster.customizeCell(() => {});

        pivotPrincipal.current.flexmonster.setReport(pivotPrincipal.current.props.report);
        pivotPrincipal.current.flexmonster.customizeCell(customizeCellGusaPrincipalConvertedor);

        pivotMediaDesvioPadrao.current.flexmonster.setReport(pivotMediaDesvioPadrao.current.props.report);
        tamanhoDataPrincipalGusa = resp.contadorPrincipal;  
        }
    }),
    ]).then(() => {  
    isRegistros = false;
    });
}
```

Como resolver ou qual a melhor maneira de utilizar ?

Answer (score 0):

O exemplo não mostra o que seria o componente Pivot, mas é provável que o uso de refs seja desnecessário neste caso (como o é em 99% dos casos). Assim como você pode passar o state **listaPrincpal** para elementos filhos, você pode também passar a função que o modifica **setListaPrincpal**. Ela está sempre atrelada a esse state e nada mais...

No elemento original ou no filho, você pode efetuar a chamada de API e, em caso de sucesso, utilizar `setListaPrincipal(resp.principal)`. Nesse momento, **listaPrincpal** deixa de ser um array vazio e se torna uma lista de coisas que você quer renderizar. O elemento pai, e quaisquer componentes filhos que utilizem **listaPrincpal** como props, serão re-renderizados com a nova lista.